# Get an url to a blog in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: html, angularjs

In the navigation bar on the Sharpoint 2013 page I'm working on there is a link called News. If I click on it I navigate to a new page where I can see all the news blogs. I'm having difficulty writing the right get request in angularjs to get this url. I need this url for an "See all" link I have on my home page that is underneath all the links that navigate to each news.

Sometimes the News url looks like this: .../sites/easySTART/frettir/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx <--- navigated from the blog list

and sometimes like this: .../sites/easySTART/frettir/default.aspx <-- navigated from the home page

it depends on where I'm navigating from.

This is my angularjs code:

```
  //+ "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + newsList + "')
  $http.get("/sites/easySTART/" + newsBlogName + "/DefaultView").
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.allNews = data.value;
    console.log($scope.allNews);
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

I've tried many different versions, this one is completely wrong I just get "404 NOT FOUND".
Now I just have the url hardcoded in my html, but I don't want that because the variable newsBlogName can vary between users of this solution, depends on the name of the blog.

This is my html and I want to use ng-href there:

```
<div class="adv_show_all_link adv_show_all_link_news">
    <a id="adv_see_all" href="https://advaniasky.sharepoint.com/sites/easySTART/frettir/default.aspx">See all</a> <!-- Needs a fix, don't want the link to be hardcoded -->
</div>
```

I'm really new to Sharepoint so I will be thankful for any help I can get :) ...hope my question is not to vague.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Default.aspx altogether using only the site path.

https://advaniasky.sharepoint.com/sites/easySTART/frettir/

The weird url woth _layouts that you see at the top is due to a feature called Minimal Download Strategy, that is used to only refresh certain parts of the page to improve performance. I personally don't like neither the URL it forms nor some issues it causes, so typically try to turn it off from Site Settings > Manage Site Features> Minimal Download Strategy (MDS).

Comment: I tried to fetch the url like this but just got undefined. Not sure if it is possible to get this url, if the API even offers it. So instead I just build up the url by using window.location.host from the homepage, extract what I don't need and add what I need. I'm completely new to this, just started working with a Sharepoint team at a software company.

Comment: Is the code being executed from the same site collection or a different one? I.e. sites/easySTART

Comment: It's injected in the webpart